# Launch application from application bundle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a helper application, which is within my main application's application bundle (in the Resources).  I'm not sure how to get the path of the application from inside the bundle and launch it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question.  I think you're saying you have an application (let's call it PrimaryApplication.app) and inside it's Resources directory there is an application you need to launch (let's call it Helper.app).  In that case you use `NSBundle`'s `-bundlePath` to get the path to the currently running application, then you append the path to your helper from there.  You can use `NSWorkspace` to launch the application once you know the path to it.

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *helperAppPath = [[mainBundle bundlePath]
  stringByAppendingString:@"/Contents/Resources/Helper.app"];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:helperAppPath];
```

Comment: The docs for `NSWorkspace` only mention `app name` as an argument, not the full path. I guess this is necessary for apps located at non-orthodox directories (e.g., inside launcher app's bundle)? Is this how Xcode launches the bundled iPhone Simulator nowadays?

Answer (score 2):

In Core Foundation, [CFBundleCopyResourceURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html) should get you the application's url.

In Cocoa, [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has equivalent `pathForResource:ofType:` and `URLForResource:withExtension:` methods.